# Qmail : auto response is polluted with email headers

Tags: qmail

When I set up auto response in qmailadmin for an account. The auto response email is sent but just after the auto response message, there is a sort of stack trace and headers of the original message:

like :

```
Received: (qmail 903 invoked by uid 508); 12 Jul 2010 20:23:55 -0000 
Received: blabla 
Received: (qmail 914 invoked from network); 12 Jul 2010 20:31:44 -0000 
Received: from blabla (ip)
somemore trace like DKIM-Signature, etc... 
*original message headers*
*original message content*
```

Is there a way to not have all this junk in the body of the email ? My users are not very happy with it... (It used to work well in the past, and I didn't change any thing recently)

If you have an idea of what happens, you are answers are welcome !

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it works be updating autorespond to the latest version (2.0.2) I don't know what version I had ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you are using the qmail-autoresponder. To check what is going wrong, I need two additional informations at the moment:

1) Content of the .qmail file with the responder
There should be something like this inside:

```
|qmail-autoresponder /path/to/autorespond/dir
```

2) The content of the autorespond directory - especially the message.txt

You can check, if the message.txt is in a correct MIME-format. It should look something like this:

```
From: "Sender of Mail" <email@yourhost.de>
User-Agent: autoresponder-system
Return-Path: <>
Subject: Re: %S
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0

Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,

Diese Emailadresse wird in den kommenden Wochen abgeschaltet. Wir m=F6chten
Sie bitten, sich zuk=FCnftig an Ihren neuen Ansprechpartner ...
```

Comment: The .qmail file contain :
    /home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/Maildir/
| /usr/local/bin/autorespond 86400 3 /home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/vacation/message /home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/vacation


and the message contains only this :

    From: myuser@mydomain.com
    Subject: Test 

    I am not here


There is nothing more than that:

file -i vacation/message 
vacation/message: message/rfc822\0117bit

Comment: I'm a little confused: The .qmail file contains the following lines: Line 1: "/home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/Maildir/" == Line 2: "| /usr/local/bin/autorespond 86400 3" == Line 3: "/home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/vacation/message" == and Line 4: "/home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/vacation"?

Comment: no all is only one line... running the command "autorespond" with 4 parameters.

Comment: autorespond - is it qmail-autoresponder or another program?

Comment: I think it is another program here the man page :

http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/autorespond

Answer (score 0):

autorespond: usage: time num message dir [ flag arsender ]

optional parameters:

flag - handling of original message:

0 - append nothing
1 - append quoted original message without attachments

Add 0 in .qmail file:
/home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/Maildir/ | /usr/local/bin/autorespond 86400 3 /home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser/vacation/message /home/vpopmail/domains/mydomain.com/myuser//vacation    0